# Does invalidating order remove order from Item cache?

Tags: atg

My assumption is that when we invalidate order by invoking `orderImpl.invalidateOrder()`, all it does is set the containers to null and thereby during the next invocation of (say) getCommerceItem(), `refreshOrder` pipeline gets executed and loads the items.

My question is - even though we invalidate the order, when the refreshOrder pipeline executes, it loads the order from the item cache (if available) indicating that order does not get removed from the cache on `orderImpl.invalidateOrder`?

Comment: Internally `invalidateOrder()` would set a flag to invalidate the repository cache. This is only triggered when you call `ensureContainers()`, which is called by `getCommerceItems()`. Are you seeing anything different?

Comment: Ah.. I have some extensions to OrderRepository -for which cache was not being cleared. Looks like in my getCustomObjects(), I would need to take care of this.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking from ATG10.2 and lower versions...

There's (what I consider) a bug in ATG's caching / Order invalidation.

As @radimpe comment suggests, if you call `OrderImpl.invalidateOrder()`, the next time anything in the Order object is accessed, the uncached `RepositoryItem`s should be used.

However, ATG's Repository caching actually works by putting the items it removes from a Cache into a WeakReference, which means that it immediately gets the item back out of the cache. So the functionality is broken, IMHO.

Unless anyone knows better?